# Variable Scope in Recursion Python quicksort

Tags: python, recursion, scope, quicksort

I am a little confused about variable scope in Python. I am suspect that the following code is not working because of its variable scope problem.

```
def partition(a):
     #return indext
     p=a[0]
     i=1
     j=1
      while j<len(a):
          if a[j]<p:
              a[j],a[i]=a[i],a[j]
              i+=1
          j+=1
      a[0],a[i-1]=a[i-1],a[0]
      return (i-1,i)

 def qsort(input_array):
      if len(input_array)<=1:
          pass
      else:
          #partition_index[0] is the index of the pivot
          #partition_index[1] is the indext after the pivot
          if len(input_array)==2:
              partition_index=partition(input_array)
          else:
              partition_index=partition(input_array)
              qsort(input_array[:partition_index[0]])
              qsort(input_array[partition_index[1]:])
```

here is the output... I don't understand why this is not working... Could someone help me with it?

here are the output:

```
 >>> a=[10,11,5,4,12,23,2]
 >>>qsort(a)
 >>>a
 [2, 5, 4, 10, 12, 23, 11]
```

If I make qsort return, it works... i am so confused.... Here is code after I put in return statement.

```
 def partition(a):
     #return indext
     p=a[0]
     i=1
     j=1
     while j<len(a):
         if a[j]<p:
             a[j],a[i]=a[i],a[j]
             i+=1
         j+=1
     a[0],a[i-1]=a[i-1],a[0]
     return (i-1,i)


 def qsort(input_array):
     if len(input_array)<=1:
         pass
     else:
         #partition_index[0] is the index of the pivot
         #partition_index[1] is the indext after the pivot
         if len(input_array)==2:
             partition_index=partition(input_array)
         else:
             partition_index=partition(input_array)
             input_array[:partition_index[0]]=qsort(input_array[:partition_index[0]])
             input_array[partition_index[1]:]=qsort(input_array[partition_index[1]:])
     return input_array
```

Answer (score 1):

`quicksort(input_array[:partition_index[0]])` doesn't actually call quicksort on the first partition of the array, it calls quicksort on a copy of the first partition of the array. Thus, your code is partitioning the array in place, then creating copies of the halves and trying to sort them (but never doing anything with the resulting arrays), so your recursive calls have no effect.

If you want to do it like this, you'll have to avoid making copies of the list with slicing, and instead pass around the whole list as well as the ranges you want your functions to apply to.